# how to change menu item's href dynamically?

Tags: url, extjs, extjs4.1

My issue is that I want to dynamically change href property of a menu item.
My menu item code is :

```
{
    text : LocalizationUtils.getMessage("Details"),
    cls : "bannerButton",
    //href : "/Project/" + project.code + "#Details",
    iconCls : "silk-form-16",
    hidden : !SecurityUtils.isUserInRole("PROJECT_DETAILS_VIEW"),
    handler :
    function () {
        if (document.URL.lastIndexOf("/Project/" + project.code + "#Details") != -1) {
            this.href = null;
        } else {
            this.href = "/Project/" + project.code + "#Details"; //,
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is : when I'm in the page pointed by the menu item, nothing has to be done. Otherwise, the page pointed by the menu item must be loaded.
Any help please?

Comment: you can'T change the href at runtime, cause it gets rendered into the html dom. if you want to change it you need to change it in the dom.

Comment: Hi, I can by using beforerender event.